# how do I install Ubuntu - difficult to get past first base!

Tags: system-installation

have downloaded the Ubuntu .iso file, double-click, roxio opens up to save an image file - but won't save to CD, external hard drive or even internal drive. I don't even need an image file! How do I get past this? I just want Ubuntu in place of XP - and yes, I realize that will wipe the computer.

Comment: Please, just read http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows This is a link, directly below the download option at http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop Please do a little research by your own before asking :)

Answer (score 0):

In order to install Ubuntu you will need to create a dvd from the iso file or make a live-usb stick and boot it.

## Steps:

**Burn .iso To A Disc:**

Step #1

Download and install a disc burning suite of some kind (you mentioned having Roxio, that should work). If you need one you can get Ashampoo Burning Studio Free from here: https://www.ashampoo.com/en/usd/pin/7110/burning-software/Ashampoo-Burning-Studio-FREE

Step #2

Launch the disc burning suite and use it to create a disc using from the iso image. You will need a dvd to write to.

Screenshots:

h#t#t#p#s#://copy.com/LKPC1rkDrlOR

h#t#t#p#s#://copy.com/9mDC9TFWOofT

h#t#t#p#s#://copy.com/MKJ078sk9ixu

h#t#t#p#s#://copy.com/msWIzVhG4mHX

h#t#t#p#s#://copy.com/mlzXXHztVkaL

Step #3

You are ready to reboot your computer and install Ubuntu. If your computer isn't configured to boot to dvd before hard drive then you will need to press your quick-boot key when the computer turns on. This key various by computer and should be stated on your screen. Typical keys are F11, F10, and Esc.

**Create A Live-Usb:**

Step #1

Download Unetbootin from: http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/

Step #2

Insert your usb stick, right click it, and format as FAT32 with default allocation size. Use quick format to save time.

Step #3

Double click on Unetbootin. It doesn't need to be installed, clicking it will run it. Then browse for you iso, and choose to install from iso to usb. Select your usb stick and click ok to proceed.

Screenshot:

h#t#t#p#s#://copy.com/xiAOdqNk9fPe

Step #4

You are ready to reboot your computer and install Ubuntu. If your computer isn't configured to boot to usb before hard drive then you will need to press your quick-boot key when the computer turns on. This key various by computer and should be stated on your screen. Typical keys are F11, F10, and Esc.